# Does the statement: $\exists z\in\mathbb{Z}\; \mbox{ such that }\; \forall b\in\mathbb{N},\;\exists\; a\in\mathbb{Q} \; :\; 3z-2b + a=0$ hold true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, logic

Consider this statement:
$$\exists z\in\mathbb{Z}\; \mbox{ such that }\; \forall b\in\mathbb{N},\;\exists\; a\in\mathbb{Q} \; :\; 3z-2b + a=0.$$

I am trying to understand if it is true or false and, if it is false, I would like to understand how deny the statement.

About me, it is true because $3z-2b +a=0\iff 2b\equiv a \ \mbox{mod } 3$, but I am not sure. Could anyone please help me to understand?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Make your life as easy as possible and see what happens for $z = 0$ (even though every integer is fine). Then, given a natural number $b$, you need to find a rational number $a$ such that $-2b + a = 0$. Do you now see whether the statement is true or false?

Comment: Thanks, now I see it is true!

Comment: Moreover, if we suppose (absurdly!) that it is false, what would be the negation of the statement?

Comment: You are welcome. The negation is the statement: For all integers $z$ there exists a natural number $b$ such that for all rational numbers $a$ we have $3z - 2b + a \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true.

Take $z=0$ then the end of the logical sentence is $\forall b \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists a \in \mathbb{Q}$ : $a=2b$ which is true.
Remark: it is also true for every other choice of $z$